# How to add domain variable to global_cardinality?

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

I'm trying to add a constraint `global_cardinality` to my program and in the [manual of SICStus Prolog](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.2.0/html/sicstus/Combinatorial-Constraints.html) is written:

> global_cardinality(+Xs,+Vals)
>
> global_cardinality(+Xs,+Vals,+Options)
>
> where Xs = [X1,...,Xd] is a list of integers or domain variables, and
>   Vals = [K1-V1,...,Kn-Vn] is a list of pairs where each key Ki is a
>   unique integer and Vi is a domain variable or an integer. True if
>   every element of Xs is equal to some key and for each pair Ki-Vi,
>   exactly Vi elements of Xs are equal to Ki.

Now I can write:

```
global_cardinality([A,B,C], [1-2, 2-1]).
```

to say that the number `1` will be used twice. The number `2` will be used just once.

But I would like to say that the number `1` will be used: `once, twice or three times`

According to the manual I need a domain variable but what is the proper syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about this, but from SWI-Prolog [page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=global_cardinality/2) I think you could try

```
...global_cardinality([A,B,C], [1-X, 2-1]), (X #= 1 #\/ X #= 2 #\/ X #= 2)...
```

or

```
?- global_cardinality([A,B,C], [1-X, 2-1]), X in 1..3, label([A,B,C]).
A = B, B = 1,
C = X, X = 2 ;
A = C, C = 1,
B = X, X = 2 ;
A = X, X = 2,
B = C, C = 1.
```

Comment: Thanks. It works the same way. My ability to google answers for SICStus Prolog is so bad that similar dummy questions will follow :(

Comment: Is there any chat room with people who are interested in Prolog? I tried IRC channel ##Prolog on Freenode and it is not much active.

Comment: Sorry, I don't known. But Prolog it's a bit out of fashion, or better, it was hot too much years ago. Then I think it's improbable you can find to chat about it.

Comment: Yes, Prolog is old but constraint programming is far from being dead as far as I know..

Comment: You're right. But I think the SemanticWeb infrastructure will rule. I hope (better, I'm proactive on this) it will revamp some interest.

Answer (score 5):

```
?- X in 1..3, global_cardinality([A,B,C], [1-X, 2-1]).
```